# How could I set no-cors on amp-script?

Tags: amp-html, ampscript

Error that I get when I use amp-script:
Access to fetch at '*amp script src*' from origin '*amp site*' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
How do I set the mode to no-cors? (Note: *amp script src* is a third party controlled file)

This is my code: `<amp-script sandbox src="*amp script src*">`

Comment: Have you tried to add `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute ?